# Как сделать, чтобы exec возвращал результат?

Tags: python-3.x, exec, eval

Есть нужда выполнить многострочный код на пайтоне, чтобы вернулся результат выполнения. `eval` не поддерживает несколько выражений, а `exec` не возвращает ничего. То есть:

```
>>> code = '''
... print('Hello, world!')
... 5 + 8 '''
>>> x = exec(code)
Hello, world!
>>> print(x)
None
>>> x = eval(code)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 3
    5 + 8
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Можно ли сделать что-то вроде

```
>>> code = '''
... print('Hello, world!')
... 5 + 8 '''
>>> x = execute_code(code)
Hello, world!
>>> print(x)
13
```

или же это невозможно?

Comment: внутри кода имя используйте: `x=5+8`. Зачем вам exec? Что вы пытаетесь сделать?

Comment: Интерпретатор python через web интерфейс. С доступом к локальным переменным этого скрипта. И есть ли способ без вывода в отдельную переменную?

Comment: всё можно, но будет ли это Питон? exec в Питоне всегда None возвращает (а на входе [`file_input`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html)). Посмотрите как ptpython, [twisted manhole](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/demo_manhole.tac) или jupyter notebook устроены.